# Javascript: Discover what function is triggerred when an option from a drop-down is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a case where when user selects an option from a drop-downn list, a function is called (the function sends an Ajax request, but that's not important here).

From the code, I can't decipher which method is being called.  In such as scenario, is there anyway that Firebug, or any other tool, can be used to locate the function that is being called?  I'm sure there is a way, but I just don't know how that can be done with Firebug.

Thanks,
Cyrus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using chrome dev tools, you could inspect the element and on the side bar in the right, select the Event Listeners tab, that will list the event listeners attached to the element.

Additional Info, in response to comment:

If you are using jquery is going to be way harder, but here we go...

Chrome dev tools again... this time go to the Sources tab instead of Elements tab. In the side bar to the right, there is an Accordion named Event Listener Breakpoint, select the event listener that you suspect is triggering your mysterious function... from there is javascript step by step debugging. if you are using jQuery, just keep hitting F11 until you are out of jQuery and into whatever other javascript you have.

Unfortunately, is not easy to debug event listeners if you don't know where is being created. You could also search your entire code base after all event listeners and add a console.log until you find the one.

Comment: When I use your suggested solution, I see about 2 dozens functions attached to the element.  Is there anyway to see dynamically which one is executed when the user selects an option?  That way, I can be certain that the specific function has been called.